# Cannot resolve symbol 'decodeResource'

Tags: android

in my application, I have these few lines of code :

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

private Bitmap[] player = new Bitmap[38];

player[0] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.Player_1);
```

Android studios gave me the error that it cannot resolve symbol 'decodeResource'. Is it due to my IDE or is there other issues causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Change the naming of your resource file to lowercase. Also change accordingly in your code

From:

```
player[0] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.Player_1);
```

To:

```
player[0] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.player_1);
```